# Suggested method of Internationalization in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, internationalization, kohana

I have a website on Kohana and I'm planning to have it multi-language. 
Now I know the way with i18n folder and inside each language folder 
there's some sort of strings.php file..  
But I want a dynamic way (on DB) so I could change the values whenever I want 
through the website.

Is there any common table schema that is usually used for multi-lang content?

Comment: though this is a good question, I think putting translated strings in db will cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can probably mimic a "resource" file in your database,

You can have a table working as a catalog for your strings, with two columns, like

```
Lang_Constants
ID, Constant_Name
1, HELLO_STRING
```

Another table with supported languages:

```
Languages
ID, Name
1, English
2, Spanish
```

and the table with the actual data:

```
ID, Language, Constant, Value
1,   1, 1, "Hello world!"
10,  2, 1, "Hola mundo!"
```

ANd you could do a query like :

```
SELECT Value from Lang_Constant_values where 
  Language = (Select ID from Languages where Name = 'English')
and
  Constant = (Select ID from Lang_Constants where Constant_Name = 'HELLO_STRING')
```